# client certificate not propagated to JSF request

Tags: apache, jsf, jboss, ssl-certificate

Hi i have this scenario :

1.) working on localhost for debuging and development porpouses

2.) apache2 as the frontend to jboss5, with ProxyPass and SSL enabled

3.) an jsf application on jboss5 which neads to read data from client certificates that access the application

4.) I have a client certificate installed in the browser and when I come to the login page of the application the broser asks me if I would like to use the certificate required by the app.

5.) When I click ok on the popup the login page is shown. To here everything ok.

6.) When I try to login and read the "**javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate**" from the request it is not there, so it looks that the certificate is not propagated from the browser to the servlet request off my app

Any hints how can I debug this further?

here is my vhost conf :

```
<VirtualHost *:443>

    ServerName a.localhost
    ProxyPass / http://b.localhost:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://b.localhost:8080/

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLOptions +ExportCertData +StdEnvVars
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW

    SSLVerifyClient optional
    SSLVerifyDepth 1
    SSLCertificateFile C:\Users\user\ssh\4pm.si_wildcard.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile C:\Users\user\ssh\4pm.si_wildcard.key
    SSLCACertificateFile C:\Users\user\ssh\ca_cert_bundle.crt
    RequestHeader set X-ClientCert %{SSL_CLIENT_CERT}s

    ErrorLog "C:/Apps/wamp/logs/4pm-error-ssl.log"
    CustomLog "C:/Apps/wamp/logs/4pm-access-ssl.log" common


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that you had to read the http headers and not the parametest of the ServletRequest

the right code is this :

```
public static X509Certificate parseCertificate(String _headerName, HttpServletRequest _request) throws CertificateException{

    String certStr = _request.getHeader("x-clientcert");

    ServletRequest req = (ServletRequest)_request;
    req.getParameter(arg0)
    //before decoding we need to get rod off the prefix and suffix
    byte [] decoded = Base64.decode(certStr.replaceAll("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----", "").replaceAll("-----END CERTIFICATE-----", ""));

    return (X509Certificate)CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509").generateCertificate(new ByteArrayInputStream(decoded));
}
```